# Insert into statement returning an error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the an error on running the below code.
   This is error message: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

```
drop table employee
create table Employee (EmpID nvarchar(50) , EmpName nvarchar(50))
insert into Employee 
values('13','SANTHOSH','3','KARTHIK')
```

Are there any ways to make the below code work.

```
drop table employee
create table Employee (EmpID nvarchar(50) , EmpName nvarchar(50))
insert into Employee 
values('13','15','17'),('BLR','HYD','CHN')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to separate your values like so:

```
drop table employee
create table Employee (EmpID nvarchar(50) , EmpName nvarchar(50))
insert into Employee
values('13','SANTHOSH') ,('3','KARTHIK')
```

Each set of values should be in parentheses.

---

Update based from comments:

Reference:

- [Table Value Constructor (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql)

prior to sql server 2008, (prior to the table value constructor)

```
drop table employee
create table Employee (EmpID nvarchar(50) , EmpName nvarchar(50))
insert into Employee values ('13','SANTHOSH')
insert into Employee values ('3','KARTHIK')
```

Comment: didn't know you can insert multiple rows with one insert statement this way. Since which SQL server version is this possible or has it always been there and I just didn't know?

Comment: It worked in 2008R2, but not in 2005. Don't know about 2008.

Comment: @RenéVogt it is a table valued constructor. They first became available with sql 2008. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql

Answer (score 3):

Use Insert statement like this way :

```
insert into Employee values('13','SANTHOSH'), ('3','KARTHIK')
```

OR

based from [@SqlZim's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2333499/sqlzim) answer comments :

```
insert into Employee values ('13','SANTHOSH')
insert into Employee values ('3','KARTHIK')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is another way to achive insert:

```
insert into Employee 
    (EmpID, EmpName)
values('13','SANTHOSH'),
    ('3','KARTHIK')
```